# Are ZFS snapshots diffs against the "main" filesystem, or diffs against each other?

Tags: zfs

I'm using ZFS snapshots to maintain access to historical versions of a backup filesystem.

```
fadedbee@backup:/backups$ sudo zfs list -t snapshot
NAME                       USED  AVAIL  REFER  MOUNTPOINT
bpool/backups@2018-06-01  96.8M      -  18.3G  -
bpool/backups@2018-06-18  96.8M      -  18.3G  -
bpool/backups@2018-06-19  96.8M      -  18.3G  -
bpool/backups@2018-06-20  96.4M      -  18.3G  -
bpool/backups@2018-06-21  96.2M      -  18.3G  -
bpool/backups@2018-06-22  63.3M      -  18.3G  -
bpool/backups@2018-06-23  62.1M      -  18.3G  -
bpool/backups@2018-06-24  62.1M      -  18.3G  -
bpool/backups@2018-06-25  96.1M      -  18.3G  -
bpool/backups@2018-06-26  96.0M      -  18.3G  -
bpool/backups@2018-06-27  97.1M      -  18.3G  -
bpool/backups@2018-06-28  96.2M      -  18.3G  -
bpool/backups@2018-06-29  62.7M      -  18.3G  -
bpool/backups@2018-06-30  63.4M      -  18.3G  -
bpool/backups@2018-07-01  63.0M      -  18.3G  -
bpool/backups@2018-07-02  96.5M      -  18.3G  -
bpool/backups@2018-07-03  96.6M      -  18.3G  -
bpool/backups@2018-07-04  96.2M      -  18.3G  -
bpool/backups@2018-07-05  96.7M      -  18.3G  -
bpool/backups@2018-07-06  62.5M      -  18.3G  -
bpool/backups@2018-07-07  62.8M      -  18.3G  -
bpool/backups@2018-07-08  63.9M      -  18.3G  -
bpool/backups@2018-07-09  97.3M      -  18.3G  -
bpool/backups@2018-07-10  96.3M      -  18.3G  -
bpool/backups@2018-07-11  97.6M      -  18.3G  -
bpool/backups@2018-07-12  98.3M      -  18.3G  -
bpool/backups@2018-07-13  63.1M      -  18.3G  -
bpool/backups@2018-07-14  62.6M      -  18.3G  -
bpool/backups@2018-07-15  63.3M      -  18.3G  -
bpool/backups@2018-07-16  97.5M      -  18.3G  -
bpool/backups@2018-07-17      0      -  18.3G  -
fadedbee@backup:/backups$ sudo zfs list
NAME            USED  AVAIL  REFER  MOUNTPOINT
bpool          21.0G  3.49T    96K  /bpool
bpool/backups  21.0G  3.49T  18.3G  /backups
```

Are the USED sizes of these snapshots the size of difference between each snapshot and now?  Or are they the size of difference between snapshots?

I know I could test this be deleting a snapshot, but it's not an important enough question to do this or set up a test scenario.

Comment: Another way to test might be to delete a large amount of data from the filesystem and see what changes occur to the `USED` and `REFER` columns

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the zfs manpage:

> When snapshots (see the "Snapshots" section) are created, their space
>        is initially shared between the snapshot and the file system, and
>        possibly with previous snapshots. As the file system changes, space
>        that was previously shared becomes unique to the snapshot, and
>        counted in the snapshot's space used. Additionally, deleting snap-
>        shots can increase the amount of space unique to (and used by) other
>        snapshots.

So the `USED` column in the zfs list output does not reflect the difference between that snapshot and some other snapshot or the dataset, but rather specifically to the data that is uniquely referenced by that snapshot.

This means that, for example, if two snapshots refer to the same 100MB file, which is deleted from the main dataset, this will not be reflected in the `USED` column of either snapshot. If one of the snapshots is deleted, it will then show in the `USED` column for the other snapshot; since it's now the only snapshot which refers to that file.

An easy way to think about it is that the `USED` column shows how much space would be made free if that dataset or snapshot was deleted.

Comment: So, if two snapshots refer to the same 100MB file, which is not in the main dataset, its size does not show up in `used` for any snapshot or dataset?

Comment: @fadedbee It will show in the `USED` column for the dataset itself, but not for the snapshots. So you'd see 100MB for the dataset, and a few KB for each snapshot.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I didn't understand.